# bash script "unexpected end of file" in simple script

Tags: bash

I have a script written in a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "/bin/uname" ]; then
   OS=`/bin/uname`;
   export OS="${OS}";
else
  echo "Unable to detect OS - modify the appropriate .bashrc to support";
if
```

If I run it, I get the following error:

```
./temp.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

However, if I  type the same script on bash prompt, it works.

(This piece of code is giving me nightmares. It is included in another large script which is failing due to these 6 lines.  I put them in a separate script temp.sh and temp.sh gives the same error)!.

regards,

JP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last line should be `fi` instead of `if`.